# Ruby - Write Data to Existing .xlsx Document

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

I have an existing xlsx file that I am trying to write data to programatically. Is there any modern solution to this for ruby? Also looked into the Google Sheets API but it's only Java and .Net.

I've searched quite a bit, and so far have checked out the following gems with no luck:

https://github.com/roo-rb/roo

https://github.com/randym/axlsx

https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL

https://github.com/cxn03651/write_xlsx

In the meantime it seems my best solution is to write to CSV, then import the CSV into the xlsx file. But it's tough to do that programmatically in the future.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with write_xlsx?

Comment: write_xlsx can't modify existing files, only create new ones - via http://cxn03651.github.io/write_xlsx/

Comment: I'd say stick with the csv solution. Its easy to write to csv then just convert than to xlsx with a dozen+ different possible tools.